# Adding fadein() and fadeout() to my slideshow project

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

Im trying to add fadein and fadeout to my slideshow project, any help or tips would be great!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.prev').on('click', function(){
    var prevImg = $('img.active').prev('.slider-inner img');
    if(prevImg.length == 0) {
      prevImg = $('.slider-inner img:last');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    prevImg.addClass('active');
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    var nextImg = $('img.active').next('.slider-inner img');
    if(nextImg.length == 0) {
      nextImg = $('.slider-inner img:first');
    }
    $('img.active').removeClass('active');
    nextImg.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

UPDATE: So I tried the fadeout/fadein function and it is currently looking like this.

```
  $( '.slideShowContainer' ).click(function() {
  $( '.active' ).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('.active').fadeIn("slow");
  });
  });
```

But the issue is, its fading in/out the image I am navigating on to, but my goal is to get it to fadeout from a previous image to fadein to the next image. I'll also include my html for the slideshow container.

```
<div class="slideShowContainer">
    <div class="slider-outer">
      <img src="images/arrow-left.png" class="prev" alt="Prev">
      <div class="slider-inner">
        <img src="images/img_1.jpg"  class="active" alt="">
        <img src="images/img_2.jpg">
        <img src="images/img_3.jpg">
      </div>
      <img src="images/arrow-right.png" class="next" alt="Next">
    </div>
  </div>
```

At the moment, it feels Im just unable to understand the basic jQuery guidelines.

Comment: You provided a goal and some code but nothing about problems with the code or problems you are having achieving your goal. People can only help when they know what the specific issue is

Comment: My bad! The current slideshow code is working perfectly, no errors no bugs, I just wanted some pointers/help in how to add the fadein and fadeout effect to my little porject.

Comment: Fade out the current one and use *complete callback* to fade in the next one. Look at examples of using the callback https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/